# What character can i use in mysql query to represent all results?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to create a php script that queries a database based on filter input from users

So essentially i want

```
select * from table where parent_id = '$filter_value'
```

However i want to apply a default value to $filter_value which will take effect if the user doesnt specify any filters, and will pull up all possible results.

I tried using * but it didnt work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Compare the value to NULL

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM table
   WHERE ($filter_value IS NULL OR parent_id = '$filter_value')
   ```
2. Dynamically create the SQL based on whether $filter_value contains a value. If it does not, your query should simply be:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM table
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the filter variable is null, or just wrap your query in an if statement:

```
SELECT * FROM baz WHERE foo = :bar OR :bar IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you asked, but it is very close and I think a better way. You can do something like this:

```
if ( empty( $filter_value ) === false ) {
    select * from table where parent_id = '$filter_value'
} else {
    select * from table
}
```

That is just an example, not good php syntax.

But the idea is that if you want to have different behaviours depending on something, then you should program it that way, for instance, with an if, that way, you know what happens in each case and control the situation, not depending on what mysql does with the empty value passed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i tried just inserting a blank space as the default var value, as in

```
$filter_value = ''
```

Solved the problem :$